# nvidia-smi not listing any processes and has no memory usage

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-prime, 19.10, nvidia-settings

Since I've installed Ubuntu on my laptop (Asus Zephyrus-G-GU502DU-GA502DU) I'm having trouble with nvidia-drivers. 
I haven't been able to see whether the GPU is actually being used or not since nvidia-smi has never listed processes.

This is the output of nvidia-smi:

```
nvidia-smi

Thu Oct 24 18:54:39 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 435.21       Driver Version: 435.21       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 166...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P0     3W /  N/A |      0MiB /  5944MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And this is the output of nvidia-settings:

```
nvidia-settings

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:8935): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 19:44:58.765: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 19:44:58.768: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 19:44:58.768: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

And some other useful(maybe) info:

```
lsmod | grep nouveau

lsmod | grep nvidia

nvidia_uvm            913408  0
nvidia_drm             49152  0
nvidia_modeset       1122304  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              19517440  8 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        184320  2 amdgpu,nvidia_drm
drm                   491520  11 gpu*_sched,drm_kms_helper,amdgpu,nvidia_drm,ttm
ipmi_msghandler       102400  2 ipmi_devintf,nvidia
i2c_nvidia_gpu         16384  0
```

```
glxgears

Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
622 frames in 5.0 seconds = 124.292 FPS
600 frames in 5.0 seconds = 119.951 FPS
600 frames in 5.0 seconds = 119.955 FPS
```

```
dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia

ii  libnvidia-cfg1-435:amd64                   435.21-0ubuntu2                      amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-435                       435.21-0ubuntu2                      all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
rc  libnvidia-compute-430:amd64                430.50-0ubuntu0.19.04.1~gpu0         amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-435:amd64                435.21-0ubuntu2                      amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-435:i386                 435.21-0ubuntu2                      i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-440:amd64                440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu19.04.2           amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-435:amd64                 435.21-0ubuntu2                      amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-435:i386                  435.21-0ubuntu2                      i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-435:amd64                 435.21-0ubuntu2                      amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-435:i386                  435.21-0ubuntu2                      i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-435:amd64                   435.21-0ubuntu2                      amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-435:i386                    435.21-0ubuntu2                      i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-435:amd64                     435.21-0ubuntu2                      amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-435:i386                      435.21-0ubuntu2                      i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-435:amd64                   435.21-0ubuntu2                      amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-435:i386                    435.21-0ubuntu2                      i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-435                   435.21-0ubuntu2                      amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-435                            435.21-0ubuntu2                      amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-435                          435.21-0ubuntu2                      amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-435                   435.21-0ubuntu2                      amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-435                   435.21-0ubuntu2                      amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.13                               all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            440.26-0ubuntu0~gpu19.10.1           amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-435                           435.21-0ubuntu2                      amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                    0.18                                 all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-435              435.21-0ubuntu2                      amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

```
dmesg -l err

[    0.313637] pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Unable to write to IOMMU perf counter.
[    0.334622] tpm_crb MSFT0101:00: can't request region for resource [mem 0xbcbe8000-0xbcbebfff]
[    2.446321] Error: Driver 'rtl8821ce' is already registered, aborting...
[    4.144178] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000040
[    5.144512] ucsi_ccg 2-0008: i2c_transfer failed -110
[    5.144517] ucsi_ccg 2-0008: ucsi_ccg_init failed - -110
```

Some notes:

- The battery runs out very fast. It never lasted more than 3 hours. Normally it's less than that.
- It has always been like this. I've tried Ubuntu 18.04, 19.04 and now, 19.10.
- It takes some to turn on/off from hibernation.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you, mate. I have the same laptop and the same problem, it will take a while for an out-of-the-box solution for AMD/NVIDIA combinations. Don't lose hope. :-)

In the meantime, what helped for me was installing the latest AMD drivers from here: https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

After rebooting, you'll see that only the AMD Radeon Vega 10 graphics are used which will help with the battery drain. Ubuntu 19.10 feels a bit slow this way however, which is why I switched to Ubuntu MATE for now. Once Ubuntu (or Manjaro) delivers proper drivers, I'm gonna switch and update you here.

Hopefully this helps you a bit.

Comment: I'll try your sugestion. If Ubuntu 19.10 gets slower i'll switch to ubuntu mate and update here for any results.

Comment: These are the only needed steps or should I remove nvidia drivers? If I switch to Ubuntu MATE, which version should I install?

Comment: The most stable way to install ubuntu mate is using `apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop`.

Comment: @David I just erased ubuntu and installed mate from live usb. Now I only need to add the AMD drivers repository?

Comment: @VictorYan Yes. I would suggest trying the repository first, and if that does not work, install the individual package for your specific device.

Comment: @Nino I installed the repository. Should I run `prime-select intel` and reboot? Because the selected option now is `nvidia`, so the nvidia gpu is running now. How do I know if it worked? What can I do to turn nvidia gpu off?

Comment: @Nino I installed the ppa and rebooted. Now powertop gives discharge rate of ~20W, What should I do now?